matplotlib: y axis format refuses to go scientific
I attempted to change the format of the matplotlib plot axis labels to scientific using the Axes.ticklabel_format function described in (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html). With the following toy code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  # Data...
T     = np.arange(0, 101, 0.01)

R_e   = 1.68799673810490
R     = np.sin(T) + R_e

  # Plotting figure     
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(T, R)

  # Attempting to set scientific format for both axes
ax.ticklabel_format(axis = 'both', style = 'scientific', scilimits = (0, 0))

  # Save figure
plt.savefig('Test.png', format = 'png')

I expected it to change both the x and y axis. It only changes the x axis.

Any help would be appreciated!

Your numbers on the y-axis are too small for the scientific formatting (i.e., the highest). If R_e would be 16.8799673810490 instead, you would get a scientific notation already. If you think about it, it would look strange having e.g., 0.2 × 10^1 as a value on the y-axis just to get a scientific notation.

Regardless of whether it is strange for this toy example or not, shouldnt it be possible? My true case is a situation where my y axis has bounds (1.6875, 1.6884), and decimal tick marks at [1.6876, 1.6878, 1.6880. 1.6882, 1.6884]. Instead of having 4 decimals, I'd prefer scientific with an offset but it refuses to do it and behaves just like this example.

You can set an offset like that manually or by using matplotlib.ticker:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


T     = np.arange(0, 101, 0.01)

R_e   = 1.68799673810490
R     = np.sin(T) + R_e

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(T, R)

formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=True, useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((1, 1))  # defines when to apply scientific notation

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()



You are absolutely right. This solved my problem - thank you.
